# Convert std::u16string to std::wstring without copy

Tags: c++, templates

I've made a bunch of UTF convertion functions with the following interface:

```
template <typename T, typename U> std::basic_string<T> UTFConvert(std::basic_string_view<U> a_String);
```

There are implementations for all the combinations of `char`, `char16_t` and `char32_t`. But now I need to add support for `wchar_t` as well. I know the size of `wchar_t` at compile time, so in theory I could just call the function with characters of the same size.

The problem is that I will have to copy the result string back into a `std::wstring`. For example, if `sizeof(wchar_t) == 2` I would end up doing something like this:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, wchar_t>, std::basic_string<T>> UTFConvert(std::basic_string_view<U> a_String)
{
    const std::u16string utf16 = UTFConvert<char16_t>(a_String);

    std::wstring wstr;
    wstr.resize(utf16.size());
    memcpy(wstr.data(), utf16.data(), utf16.size() * sizeof(wchar_t));

    return wstr;
}
```

It seems kind of wasteful to copy the string like that. Is there a way to avoid this, without re-implementing the same code twice for the different types?

Comment: `char16_t` is a distinct type from `wchar_t` even if they are the same size.  Convertimg one to the other without a copy has aliasing issues that are tricky to get around.  Are you concerned about that?  Habe you identified this as a bottleneck?  Can we rewrite the calling code in any way?

Comment: These functions are only used when it is known that the source is encoded in UTF. I am not assuming the encoding of these characters in general.

Comment: this has nothing to do with encoding, it has to do with rules of the C++ type system.  Encoding is about *values stored*, aliasing is about accessing values and what you can or cannot do through what types.

Comment: Would you then care to point out those issues? Simply stating that they exist without explanation only distracts and prevents us from solving the original problem.

Comment: So you are saying you are concerned about that.  There are two more clarifying questions you are choosing not to answer in my first comment.

Comment: I don't know if I should be concerned, because I can't guess what issues you are seeing, and therefore I cannot say whether or not I care about those issues. As for the other 2 questions: 2. No I have not, but that doesn't mean that this code cannot be improved. There is a clear improvement here, the only question is how to implement it without duplicating code. 3. The calling code is irrelevant here, its is a generic conversion function that can be used anywhere.

Comment: can't you just write a *generic* version of your "UTFConvert<char16_t,char16_t>" specialization, to be used for both char16_t *and* wchar_t (whenever sizeof(char16_t) == sizeof(wchar_t) holds true) ?

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes Hmmm so I'd specialize the functions by `sizeof(T)` instead of the specific character type. That might actually work, I'll give it a shot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has been solved by specializing the functions on the size of T instead of the specific character type:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
std::enable_if_t<sizeof(T) == 2, std::basic_string<T>> UTFConvert(std::basic_string_view<U> a_String);
```

Just sprinkle a few `static_assert`s on there for sanity, and everything works perfectly!

Thank you @MassimilianoJanes for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You are in a corner of C++ where the standard has a few rough spots.

There are a few theoretical pitfalls here.

The first of which is that it is not legal in C++ to dereference a `wchar_t*` on a buffer of `char16_t`, and vice versa.  This problem is known as "strict aliasing".

This can be worked around to a limited extent by careful copying back and forth and construction if you have a fixed size buffer.  However, there is a flaw in the C++ standard that makes creating dynamic sized arrays impossible to do "manually" without invoking `new[]` on exactly the type in question (it is impossible under the standard for user code to implement `std::vector` or similar).

This is a defect in the standard, but it is as far as I know unresolved at this point.

So the question becomes, how closely do you want to follow the standard, and how much do you want something that just works?

The closest I can get to standards-compliant code to solve your problem is this:

---

Write a new `UTFConvert_to_sink` function.

```
template<class T>
struct tag_t {};

template<class CharType, class Sink>
void UTFConvert_to_sink(std::basic_string_view<CharType> from, tag_t<CharType> to, Sink&& sink) {
  for (CharType c : from)
    sink(c);
}
template<class Sink>
void UTFConvert_to_sink(std::basic_string_view<char> from, tag_t<std::char16_t> to, Sink&& sink); // TODO

template<class Sink>
void UTFConvert_to_sink(std::basic_string_view<char> from, tag_t<std::char32_t> to, Sink&& sink); // TODO


template<class Sink>
void UTFConvert_to_sink(std::basic_string_view<char16_t> from, tag_t<char> to, Sink&& sink); // TODO

template<class Sink>
void UTFConvert_to_sink(std::basic_string_view<char16_t> from, tag_t<std::char32_t> to, Sink&& sink); // TODO

template<class Sink>
void UTFConvert_to_sink(std::basic_string_view<char32_t> from, tag_t<char> to, Sink&& sink); // TODO

template<class Sink>
void UTFConvert_to_sink(std::basic_string_view<char32_t> from, tag_t<std::char16_t> to, Sink&& sink); // TODO
```

note that these are only templated on the `Sink`.  How the `Sink` works should be clear from my templated "same to same".

The `UTFConvert` can be written on top of the above as follows:

```
template<class To, class From>
std::basic_string<To> UTFConvert( std::basic_string_view<From> from ) {
  std::basic_string<To> retval;
  UTFConvert_to_sink( from, tag_t<To>{}, [&retval]( To c ) {retval.push_back(c);} );
}
```

which handles every type in question.

Now what is left is `wchar_t` in `UTFConvert_to_sink`.

```
using char_type_same_size_as_wchar_t = std::char16_t; // or char32_t depending on platform.

template<class From, class Sink>
void UTFConvert_to_sink(std::basic_string_view<From> from, tag_t<wchar_t> to, Sink&& sink) {
  UTFConvert_to_sink( from, tag_t<char_type_same_size_as_wchar_t>{}, [&sink](auto c) {
    wchar_t wc = c;
    sink( wc );
  });
}
```

and I think everything is a-ok standards-wise.  And the wchar_t function should compile down to literally nothing.

Things do get messy if you want to support from-`wchar_t` due to the standards defect about it being not possible to create arrays without invoking `new T[]`.  We can get close where we launder each element.

```
template<class U, class T>
U* landry_pod( T* in ) {
  static_assert( sizeof(T)==sizeof(U) );
  static_assert( std::is_trivially_copyable<T>{} && std::is_trivially_copyable<U>{} );
  char buff[sizeof(T)];
  std::memcpy( buff, in, sizeof(T) );
  U* r = ::new( (void*)in ) U;
  std::memcpy( r, buff, sizeof(U) );
  return r;
}
```

`landry_pod<OutType>` is a funny function in that it compiles down to zero instructions (try it), but it is a legal way to turn a pointer to a trivially copyable object of type T and get a pointer to a trivially copyable object of the same size U that contains the exact same bytes.

So the closest I can get is to run over the `basic_string_view<wchar_t>`, `laundry_pod` each element in turn, then take the pointers and create a `basic_string_view<char16_t>` with them, then feed them to `UTFConvert_to_sink`.

Now, *all of this is ridiculous gymnastics* to work around strict aliasing rules in the standard, and it doesn't even go far enough to actually generate completely defined behavior.

Note that I wrote a `sink` that takes individual characters; writing one that is more advanced (ie, takes a length separate from the characters, and/or allows you to feed in a sequence) can also be done.